# How to set up the new instance structure for activities when receiving intent arguments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

For Fragments, it has been advised to set them up in the following way if arguments are to be expected:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARGUMENTS_NUM = "arguments_num";
    private int mNum;

    public static MyFragment newInstance(int num) {
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARGUMENTS_NUM, num);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mNum = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENTS_NUM);
    }
}
```

How would this sort of structure be accomplished with Activities when receiving intents, which also sometimes expect arguments?

Answer (score 0):

try this
receive

```
Bundle arg = getArguments();
    if(arg!=null){
     String   articleID = getArguments().getString("ArticleId");
    }
```

set Argument